# Analysis of a operator in $L_2 [0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators, adjoint-operators

> Let $T:L_2 [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ define by $$ \int_0^1 f\left( \frac{x}{2} \right) e^x dx$$
> Is $T$ bounded? If $T$ is bounded compute $||T||$, Is $T$ compact? Compute the adjoint of T.

First, when I try to bound $||Tf||$ I'm not sure how work with $ f\left( \frac{x}{2} \right)$ for the compacity of $T$ I try to use the definition of compact operators but I don't sure to these is the right way.

Any hint or suggestion I will very grateful

Comment: change variable $y=x/2$.

Comment: After changing variables apply the fact: the linear functional $x\mapsto \langle x,y\rangle $ has the norm equal $\|y\|.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc oh I see that is for the Riesz Theorem right?

Comment: Yes. Actually it follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.  The main part of the Riesz Theorem is the fact that every bounded linear functional on the Hilbert space is of the form $x\mapsto \langle x,y\rangle $ for some $y.$ You do not need the full strength of the Riesz Theorem.